# SharePoint 2010 PeoplePicker Control Not Displaying User Data

Tags: sharepoint-2010, user-profile, peoplepicker, sharepoint-userprofile

**Update - 27/08/2012**

My company has spoken to Microsoft Support, and this behaviour has been described as "by design" for claims based authentication. Hmmm.  The workaround suggested by Microsoft was to develop a custom claims provider that would populate the missing fields.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

In a test SharePoint environment, I have configured the User Profile Service, and the user profiles have been successfully populated into the UPS using the User profile Synchronization Service from the targeted domain.   The data in the user profiles correctly reflects the data for the user in AD.  In particular, the data for the following fields (the fields shown in a People Picker used on a CBA site) are showing correctly in UPS:

- Display Name
- E-mail
- Address
- Title
- Department
- Presence
- Work Phone
- Location

However, on a site that uses claims based authentication, whenever a search is made for a specific user in the People Picker control, when the user is displayed in the List View, no values are being displayed for Work Phone or for Location, even when values are appearing in UPS and in AD. The correct details are being displayed in the People Search results for specified users, and in the user’s Profile pages.

The search service metadata properties for the various fields (WorkTelephone, Location) have been checked and are correctly mapped.

I thought that column data was missing because of a synchronization issue between the UPS and the site’s User Information List.  I tested this by updating various field values (including the work phone and location) for a specific user in UPS.  When the User profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization timer job was ran, the data in the Profile page, the people search results and the information displayed for the user in the User information List all updated correctly.  The information for the same user in the People Picker is not updated – the work telephone and location are still not displaying values, and the other fields such as display name are not displaying the updated information.

The current SharePoint patch level (build version) for each environment is 14.0.6120.5006 (SharePoint 2010 Server with SP1 and April 2012 CU applied).

Can anyone help identify why the user information shown in the PeoplePicker control isn't showing the correct information?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue - UPS populates correctly from AD but none of the updates are making it into the SharePoint sites (2010/SQL2012).

Have reset IIS and even restarted the servers. The delete all users and re-add them strategy doesn't work for us.

---

Found a solution that works for what we needed.... 
http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/12/updating-sharepoint-2010-user-information/
Was not so much the script as the insight...

set-spuser -identity 'domain\username' -web http://yoursitehere.com -email 'username@yoursitename.com'

Powershell wants the quote marks. I wanted the email address to show up!

Pretty good examples in PS (get-help set-SPUser)